# How do I show a Jpeg photo from LDAP with JSP?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, ldap

I'm trying to display a jpeg photo from the LDAP server with a servlet, but I cant show the image correctly with the code below.

There are many posts suggesting casting the data, like `(byte[])entry.get("jpegPhoto")` but that won't compile for me.

Is there any way to display the photo directly? Many thanks.

```
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Entry;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class DisplayLdapImage extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //response.setContentType("image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");    
    this.execute(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //response.setContentType("image/jpeg charset=UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 
    this.execute(request, response);
}

private void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    //get image from ldap server
    String employeeId = request.getParameter("uid");
    Entry entry = ldapController.getEntryByEmployeeId(employeeId);
    try
    {
        response.getOutputStream().write(entry.get("jpegPhoto").get().getBytes());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your GET method you are missing the semicolon between image/jpeg and charset=UTF-8.  And involving a charset could be causing a problem since images don't actually use charsets. (Do a search for "image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8" and you'll see it can cause problems.) So you should just use:

```
 response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried this but still not working. I think  I have to modify the original post.

Comment: If you write it out to a file byte by byte does it come out as a valid jpeg? It could be that its a different format (PNG, GIF).